# Iterate over an object and add new attributes

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

So I have an object. I want to iterate over it and return same object but with additional attributes. I have done the following but it returns old data.

```
_.each(data, function(item) {
          _.extend(item, {name: item.first});

        });
```

Ok i have even tried, still no luck

```
 _.each(data, function (item){


        item.name = item.first;
         return item;

    });
```

Comment: Your code does not "`return`" anything. So what are you talking about? What's the input (`data`), what output do you get, and how is that unexpected?

Comment: You need iterate recursive your object?

Answer (score 0):

That is beacause extend copies the second object's properties in the first: http://underscorejs.org/#extend

Im not sure what you want, but won't this fix it?

```
_.each(data, function(item) {
    //set item.first property on item.name
    item.name = item.first;
});

//var data is still the same array with same objects, but all the objects inside are updated.
```

### based on your comment

here you go, what you want:

```
var yourNewArray = data.map(function(item){
  //clone item so you dont have reference to object in dat array
  var newItem = _.clone(item);
  //set property on another property
  newItem.name = newItem.first;
  return newItem;
}
```

## another way

Another way if you only want that specific proprety as object array:

```
var yourNewArray = data.map(function(item){
  return { name : item.first}; //return object with property name, with value from original object.first property
}
```

Remember: an array contains an list of object **References**. So you cant simply change the objects, you need to clone them so you don't change the original array.

Comment: [extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) clearly does not [clone](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) the destination object.

Comment: then you need to clone the old first

Comment: @Bergi from the original documentation: `Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object, and return the destination object. It's in-order, so the last source will override properties of the same name in previous arguments.` I think my first sentence sounds pretty similar

Comment: @joelharkes: Except that the destination object is the first and the source object(s) are the second (third, …) ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use `Array.map` for this

```
var newData = data.map(function(i){
i['name'] = i.first;
return i;
})
```

Comment: …assuming `data` is an array. And when you mutate the items, using `map` instead of `forEach` doesn't really make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
 a : { first : 'albert'},
 b : { first : 'bob' },
 c : { first : 'charle'}
};

for ( var item in data ) {
     data[item].name = data[item].first;
}
```

If you want to change an object you should not "return" it, because is nonsense, javascript doesn't copy object anyway, return will give a link to the same data object, and if you change this object will change data too, if you really nead a diferent object, you will need do a deep copy of your object.

Exemple:

```
a = {name:'albert'};
b = a;

b.name = 'bob';

console.log(a);
```

will show `{ name: 'bob' }`